# Repeat panda data frame processes for multiple text files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to read a large number of text files, process the text files using pandas data frames and then output a new text file for each input file.

My code works when I process a single text file but not when I try and loop through multiple text files.

My code for a single file is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('name.txt',sep='\s+',skiprows=22, header=None, names=header_list,)
df['offset'] = df.iloc[0,1]
df['offset_removed'] = df['mufluor']-df['offset']
df.to_csv('name_2.txt',index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

I have been trying to use this code to cycle through multiple files:

```
all_files=glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt"))
for file in all_files:
    file_name = os.path.split(file)[1]
    header_list=["energy","mufluor","io","ifluor_DT","ifluor_raw","counttime","itrans","irefer"]
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name,sep='\s+',skiprows=22, header=None, names=header_list,)
    df['offset'] = df.iloc[0,1]
    df['offset_removed'] = df['mufluor']-df['offset']
```

But this doesn't seem to work as the values in my data frames now seem to be strings? Rather than floats...I am not sure why the type of data in my data frame has changed?

Comment: Probably because in some of your files, you have rows with string values in the `mufluor` and `offset` columns.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. I've tested the code for a single file on two of my text files and for both of those it worked fine. I then tried to run the for loop just for those two files and it didn't run. When I run df.dtypes for the 'single file' data frame every column is listed as 'float64' whereas df.dtypes for the 'for loop' data frame every column is listed as 'object'

Comment: including the 2 first files?

Comment: Are you sure you have to skip 22 rows on each file? If you have an error, update your post with the full traceback.

Comment: Yes, I ran the for loop only for the first two files, and when I checked df.dtypes it listed every column is object

Comment: Yes, the first 22 lines are just info about the data. I'll try and run the for loop with some of my other text files, incase one of the two I have been running the code with is odd in some way.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer**

Try:

```
header_list=["energy","mufluor","io","ifluor_DT","ifluor_raw","counttime","itrans","irefer"]


df1 = pd.read_csv('name1.txt',sep='\s+',skiprows=22, header=None, names=header_list,)
df1['offset'] = df1.iloc[0,1]
df1['offset_removed'] = df1['mufluor']-df1['offset']
df1.to_csv('name_1.txt',index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')


df2 = pd.read_csv('name2.txt',sep='\s+',skiprows=22, header=None, names=header_list,)
df2['offset'] = df2.iloc[0,1]
df2['offset_removed'] = df2['mufluor']-df2['offset']
df2.to_csv('name_2.txt',index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

The output is what you expect?

Comment: This worked. I've also managed to make the 'for loop' code work now. I didn't change the code I just restarted my terminal and Jupyter notebooks and made a 'new practise' folder. So there must have been some 'memory' that was causing the code to fail. Thank you for your help